# How come my my HTC Desire Z sometimes doesn't notify me about a new SMS?

Tags: sms, htc-desire-z

My HTC Desire Z has developed an issue (well several, but just one for this question) where it doesn't always notify me of a new message. When a new message arrives, I expect:

- the phone to beep (well ring tone), and
- there to be an indicator in the notification area until I look at the message or clear notifications.

This does happen the majority of the time, but sometimes neither of these things happen. But if I open the Messages app, there is the new message. This is really quite annoying, so does anyone know ways to fix this? Are there alternative SMS apps that might be different, or is this functionality an OS thing? Would using, say, CyanogenMod fix it, or at least be worth a try? Is it possible that the formatting of particular contacts would cause such a problem? Any other ideas?

Version info:

- Phone: HTC Desire Z (Vodafone UK)
- Android: 2.2.1
- Kernel: 2.6.32.21-g540976a htc-kernel@and18-2 #1
- Build Number: 1.72.161.1 CL296256 release-keys

Comment: I am having the same problem. I am not very technical at all and this problem is very annoying! In addition to not always showing a new message, when it does the notification tool bar doesn't clear as it used too. I have checked for updates and there don't appear to be any. Could you tell me more about the Handcent SMS app please? Or any other suggestions on how to fix the exisiting problem?!

Comment: I am having the same problem. I removed Handcent because it was performing abysmally slow. I guess we'll all have to lean heavily on HTC for an update. At least messages don't take minutes to send anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're still receiving the messages, the app must just be buggy.  You could try using the [Handcent SMS](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.handcent.nextsms) app instead.

Comment: I've switched to that now, and I'll see how I go.

Comment: This has solved it for me :) Since switching to Handcent I haven't missed a test message, and additionally my phone hasn't crashed, which previously it was doing rather regularly. Thank you.

Comment: Great! Glad it worked.

Comment: Wow, that so didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @PP01 Feel free to post a "real" solution.  In lieu of one, Handcent is obviously a useful workaround.

Comment: Actually Handcent is rubbish. I had to remove it because it was severely slow. Ultimately HTC need to repair the messaging system. Like I said, at least messages don't take a full minute to merely send (like they did before Christmas). Point is, we want to know how to make the stock messaging app notify about messages correctly: not just use a 3rd party product - it's a suggestion but certainly not an "answer".

Comment: @PP01 **This isn't your question**. Not to mention you can't make buggy software magically work correctly, and this sounds like a bug. I've also never heard anyone complain about Handcent. If this isn't what you want, then post your own question.  (Link to this one and explain why you're not interested in a workaround, so that it's not closed as a duplicate).

Comment: I've got news for you: lots of people read this site. Lots of people have similar problems (and I am experiencing the same problem). So not everyone that experiences the same problem posts the same question. Oh, and by the way, you've heard someone complain about Handcent now: me!

Comment: I don't see how that's relevant.  This question has been answered to the asker's satisfaction and is not likely to receive any more answers.  If you would like this answered to *your* satisfaction, it's unlikely to happen here.  So I suggest you ask your own question.  And since we are no longer talking about the content of my answer, please take this to [Meta](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/) if you want to discuss it further.

Answer (score 1):

How much free internal space do you have on your phone?  When my phone has too many services running or doesn't have enough free internal space then services will get killed left and right, therefore the messaging service won't run to alert me of a new message.  Try uninstalling some apps or moving them to the SD card.  You can check for any unnecessary running services under Settings -- > Applications --> Running Services.

Comment: I have 846MB of internal phone storage. The running services looks OK aswell - there are 6 services listed, and at the bottom the bar is 2/3 green (Avail: 113MB + 126MB in 16). But I shall check this again when I've missed a message to see if more stuff is in there.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and all I did to fix it was restart my phone!  Worked like a charm!